# Are the integral and differential definitions of Ito process equivalent?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

I think an **ito process** $X_t$ can be [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_calculus#It%C3%B4_processes) as

$$X_t := X_0 + \int_0^t\sigma_s dB_s + \int_0^t\mu_s ds.$$

(Is this an Ito drift-difussion process?)
(Why use the subscript $s$? Eg. why is it $\sigma_s$ and not just $\sigma$?)

And I've also seen:

$$dX_t := \sigma_t dB_t + \mu_t dt$$

Are the 2 definitions equivalent, and why (not)?
(One seems to be the integral of the other. Which would mean one is the derivative of the other, which would mean there is an **Ito derivative**?)

Comment: The second is just a notation whose definition is the first

Comment: To add to the succint first comment and answer your last question: There is ***no*** Ito derivative.

Comment: It looks like you have edited this post a couple of times to include the tag [tag:ito-calculus].  This tag doesn't already exist on the site, and it is generally considered bad form to create a new tag without consulting the community, first.  New tags should be proposed in the [tag management thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35451/).  For further discussion, https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/tagging .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this an Ito drift-difussion process?

yes

> Why use the subscript $s$? Eg. why is it $\sigma_s$ and not just $\sigma$?

because it depends on time too eg. see [Solution to General Linear SDE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1788853/solution-to-general-linear-sde)

> And I've also seen:
> $$dX_t := \sigma_t dB_t + \mu_t dt$$
> Are the 2 definitions equivalent, and why (not)?
> (One seems to be the integral of the other. Which would mean one is the derivative of the other, which would mean there is an **Ito derivative**?)

Yes, they are equivalent. And in general for semimartingales, they always mean them in integral form (think of weak derivatives in Sobolev). The main issues are

- Brownian motion is not differentiable [Proving Brownian motion is not monotone](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2963855/proving-brownian-motion-is-not-monotone)
- generally any martingale that is differentiable is actually constant [Does there exist an almost surely differentiable martingale?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/397639/does-there-exist-an-almost-surely-differentiable-martingale)

> Indeed, if a martingale is a.s. everywhere differentiable, then its quadratic variation is a.s $0$. So, by the Burkholder--Davis--Gundy inequality, the martingale is a.s. constant.

Comment: This is a very nice answer, thank you.